# copy table to another with condition and join

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-insert, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to copy from table to another with condition and join and when I created it I get an error.

```html
INSERT INTO [ax].[WaitingKitchenStatus]
(
    [TRANSACTIONID]--1
    , [LineNote]--2
    , [Item]--3
    , [CreationDate]--4
    , [CreationTime]--5
    , [active]--6
    ,[Gruop]--7
)

SELECT ab.COMMENT
 ,[ax].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION].[NAME]
    , ab.[ITEMID]
FROM ax.RetailTransactionSalesTrans ab
inner join [ax].[INVENTTABLE] on ab.[ITEMID] =[ax].[INVENTTABLE].[ITEMID]
inner join [ax].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION] on [ax].[INVENTTABLE].PRODUCT =[ax].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION].[PRODUCT]
LEFT JOIN ax.[WaitingKitchenStatus] a ON 
a.[TRANSACTIONID]=ab.COMMENT--1
and a.[LineNote]=[ax].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION].[NAME]--2
and a.[Item]=ab.[ITEMID]--3
and a.[CreationDate]=GETDATE()--4
and a.[CreationTime]= CONVERT(time, GETDATE())--5
and a.active= 1--6
and a.Gruop=''--7
where ab.TRANSACTIONSTATUS !=1
and ab.RECEIPTID !=''
and ab.COMMENT !=''
and NOT EXISTS(select * from ax.[WaitingKitchenStatus] where active= 1 and [TRANSACTIONID]=ab.COMMENT)
```

I got this error

> Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: The error seems obvious.  Your `insert` is expecting 7 columns but you are only providing 3.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help other people figure out what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: thanks for replay but other tables no need to copy from other table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your premise of not needing the other columns does not make sense, neither does your query.  Alias referencing could be significantly cleaned up and trying to follow your structure with different column names a bit of a mess. Sorry for honesty, but lets get to the basics of SQL insert from...  As Gordon mentioned, you are trying to insert 7 columns but only selecting 3.  That is your failure.  It should be in the format example of

```
insert into YourTable
   ( YourColumn1,
     YourColumn2,
     YourColumnX,
     YourColumnZ
   )
   select
         HYH.YourColumn1,
         HYH.YourColumn2,
         HYH.YourColumnX,
         HYH.YourColumnZ
      from
         HoweverYourHaveOtherTablesAndJoins HYH
```

Notice the exact same number of columns inserted as selecting.  Now, looking at your query FROM/JOINs.  It is typically easier to have abbreviation somewhat reference the original table name.  Ex:

```
FROM ax.RetailTransactionSalesTrans ab
  inner join [ax].[INVENTTABLE] on ab.[ITEMID] = [ax].[INVENTTABLE].[ITEMID]
  inner join [ax].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION] 
     on [ax].[INVENTTABLE].PRODUCT =[ax].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION].[PRODUCT]
  LEFT JOIN ax.[WaitingKitchenStatus] a ON … etc.
```

I would change to strip all the [] context and apply better use of table alias name references vs "a", "ab", and others using full database.table.column references.

```
INSERT INTO ax.WaitingKitchenStatus
(
   TransactionID, 
   LineNote, 
   Item, 
   CreationDate,
   CreationTime, 
   Active,
   -- Is this really Gruop? or Group?  If Group, you would need 
   -- `ticks` around it to not be confused with Group by clause
   Gruop
)
SELECT
      RTST.Comment,
      EPT.Name,
      RTST.ItemID,
      WKS.CreationDate,
      WKS.CreationTime,
      WKS.active,
      WKS.Gruop
   from
      ax.RetailTransactionSalesTrans RTST
         inner join ax.InventTable InvT
            on RTST.ItemID = InvT.ItemID
            inner join ax.EcoresProductTranslation EPT
               on InvT.Product = EPT.Product
               LEFT JOIN ax.WaitingKitchenStatus WKS
                  ON RTST.Comment = WKS.TransactionID  -- 1
                 and EPT.Name = WKS.LineNote           -- 2
                 and RTST.ItemID = WKS.Item            -- 3
                 and WKS.CreationDate = GETDATE()      -- 4
                 and WKS.CreationTime = CONVERT(time, GETDATE())  --5
                 and WKS.active = 1                   -- 6
                 and WKS.Gruop = ''                   -- 7
   where 
          RTST.TransactionStatus != 1
      and RTST.ReceiptID != ''
      and RTST.Comment != ''
      and NOT EXISTS( select * 
                         from ax.WaitingKitchenStatus WKS2
                         where WKS2.active= 1 
                           and WKS2.TransactionID = RTST.Comment )
```

I am sure you can agree that without all the [xx].[xxxxx] brackets and database.table.column references now abbreviated with more meaningful alias references is easier to follow.  Also, indentation helps readability to find where A joins to B joins to C, etc.

It appears you have already included indications of the --1, --2, etc to --7 representing where your 7 columns are, that is what needs to be part of the select columns being inserted.  And changing column name to a context (ex: TransactionID = Comment?  I don't think ANYONE would have guessed that correlation, but it appears to be how your restaurant system works things.

Finally, while LEFT-JOINING to your kitchen status vs JOIN, I can only guess but wont.  Hopefully, some of what I have offered in here make sense to get you going, but with Left-Join to kitchen status MAY allow NULL values to be inserted into those respective columns during the insert, but hey, its what I'm working with from what was provided.